# How this context can be modeled (fulfilling the normal forms)?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm a beginner in DB. I have studied some basic examples but now I'm studying more complex cases that involve many tables related to each other. I'm studying how to model a DB for a conference system but there is a detail that seems difficult to model.

The detail is, a conference can have multiple registration types and each registration type can have user defined fields, for example,

- the conference organizer can create a conference with a registration type "General" that needs the fields "name, email" that need to be filled in by the user that does the registration for each participant that he is registering.
- he can create another registration type "vip" with the fields "name, email, phone" that need to be filled in by the user that does the registration for each participant that he is registering.

Do you know how to add this context to the diagram (fulfilling the normal forms)?

**Diagram (without that user defined fields part)**

[image]

Comment: This question may have an answer here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193394/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-several-mutually-exclusive-one-to-one-relationships/193401#193401

Comment: The specifics are very different, but the design issue is the same

Answer (score 1):

I always go with the multiple table approach

```
registration
    id (for gods sake don't use an int)
    type
    name
    email

registration_vip
    id (same value as corresponding registration row)
    phone

//get all the vip registrations with extra fields
select * 
    from 
        registration r
    left join 
        registration_vip v
        on v.id = r.id
    where
        r.type ='vip'
```

Obviously, if you have several types and you want to get the all then you have to do more than one query. **RESIST THE URGE TO WRITE DYNAMIC SQL**

However, you can run them all in a single call and return multiple datasets if required, so there is really no performance impact.

I much prefer this over the alternative 'lots of null columns' approach. Mainly due to lack of nulls, but also the ease of adding new types without impacting the existing tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But  Im not understanding well, because for example, the registration table in the diagram is to store things like status (complete, incomplete, etc) and things related to a registration. A registration type can be general, can be vip but can be any other thing depending on what name the conference organizer uses for the registration type. And in a specific conference a organizer can create a registration type "general" requiring only "name and email" but in another conference he can create also a registration type "general" but request different fields.

Comment: yes your question isn't clear, is it the conference which has a name and email or the registration for the conference? It seems to make most sense to me if the registration has those fields, but you could obviously have it the other way around if desired

Comment: A registration stores the status and registration and also the user that did the registration. A conference  has a name, but the conference table should be ok. Then the RegistrationType table is to store the registration types that can be "general", "vip" but can be any other registration type that a user that create a conference can add to the conference, so can be any value. But this RegistrationType table should also be ok. The issue is that how to model this part that the conference organizer can create for each conference many registraation types and in each registration type he can add..

Comment: can the organiser make up any random field they choose, or are they restricted to some known set?

Comment: ..he can add different fields, for the "general" RegistrationType he can add 5 custom fields like name, email, etc, for another RegistrationType for the same conference he can add only 2 custom fields, and also can create more RegistrationTypes, any number of RegistrationType that he wants, and for each registration type add any number of custom fields that are specific to that RegistrationType.

Comment: yes, but when you say 'specific to the registration type' are those defined in advance and the organiser ticks the ones they want, or could they add , "what is your favorite pokemon?" or any random question?

Comment: yes, they can add any question that they want, the questions/custom fields are not pre defined for the registration type.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate answer for "Organiser can make up custom fields at run time"

If you allow the user to create custom fields you have three equally bad solutions

1. Add x (say 10) varchar(max) fields customField1, customField2... etc to your table to store the data. Have a seperate table with the user defined names of these fields per registration type

This is the simplest but most limited. You have a max number of custom fields you can store without changing the table and reporting off them is a nightmare.

2. add extra tables:

such as

```
questions
    id
    registrationTypeId
    text ('what is your favourite colour?')

answers
    id
    questionId
    answer
```

This is better as you can have as many fields as you want. Reporting is slightly easier you can pivot on the question id and stuff.

However it becomes more complicated when you want to add validation and different types of answer number, date, drop down etc

3. Use a document type and store in a single field such as xml or json

Impossible to report against, but the most flexible in terms of validation and presentation. You could store a whole html form for example.

Comment: Thanks again! In the solution "2" the type of the field (text, select, etc) could be stored in the questions table right? And in the solution "3" the diagram above can stay the same and its just necessary to add for example a "questions" table with a structure like (idQuestion, registrationType(fk), fields)?  And this fields column stores the question and the answer? Like: "{"name": "John", "email": "test@mail.test", "phoneNumber": "0000", "zip code": "000000"}
"